# How to update child view on model change in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using MVVM design pattern in my swiftUI application. There is nested Model as well and I am toggling the status on tap of a button within the model and based on the status I want change the color of the button. There are many buttons but I want to update the status on which the user is tapping, I have tried with my below code but it's not working :(

Model:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class SeatLayoutModel : Codable, ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let status : Bool?
    let data : [SeatData]?
    let error : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case status = "status"
        case data = "data"
        case error = "error"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        status = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .status)
        data = try values.decodeIfPresent([SeatData].self, forKey: .data)
        error = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .error)
    }

}

class SeatData : Codable, ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let seats : [Seats]?
    let totalQuantity : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case seats = "seats"
        case totalQuantity = "totalQuantity"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        seats = try values.decodeIfPresent([Seats].self, forKey: .seats)
        totalQuantity = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .totalQuantity)
    }

}

class Seats : ObservableObject, Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let seatType : String?
    let status : Int?
    @Published var color: Color = Color.red
    
    @Published var isSelected = false
    
    func toggleIsSelectedStatus() {
        isSelected = !isSelected
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case seatType = "seatType"
        case status = "status"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        seatType = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .seatType)
        status = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .status)
        
        if isSelected {
            color = Color.blue
        } else {
            color = Color.gray
        }
        
    }

}
```

View Model (API call)

```
import Foundation
class SeatLayoutViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var totalSeats:[Seats] = [Seats]()
    func getSeatMasterData() {
        //mobile/seatConfig/seatMaster
        let url = Constants.baseUrl + Constants.API.seatMaster
        
        APIService.shared.makeApiTypeRequest(url: url, param: nil, methodType: .get, expecting: SeatLayoutModel.self) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let respData):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if respData.status ?? false {
                        print("Seat master data recieved \(respData.data?.first?.seats?.count)")
                        if let totalseat = respData.data?.first?.seats {
                            self.totalSeats = totalseat
                        }
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Something went wrong")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Parent View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SeatSelectionView: View {
    
    @StateObject var seatLayoutViewModel = SeatLayoutViewModel()
    
    @State var setas = [Seats]()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                VStack(spacing: -5) {
                    
                    HStack {
                        GateSectionView(data: $seatLayoutViewModel.totalSeats)
                            .frame(width: 780)
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                    
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .padding(.bottom)
                
            }
            
        }
        .onAppear {
            seatLayoutViewModel.getSeatMasterData()
        }
        
    }
}
```

Child View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct GateSectionView: View {
    @Binding var data:[Seats]
    private let adaptiveColumns = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 30))
    ]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            LazyVGrid(columns: adaptiveColumns) {
                ForEach(Array(data.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, element in
                    
                    Button {
                        data[index].toggleIsSelectedStatus()
                        //element.toggleIsSelectedStatus()
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(index + 1)")
                            .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    .background(element.color)
                    .cornerRadius(3)
                    
                    //Text("Helo")
                }
            }.padding(10)
            Spacer()
            
        }
        
        .cornerRadius(12)
        .frame(width: 780)
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Nested ObservableObjects are not really supported. There doesn’t seem to be any reason your model cannot be structs. Changing your code in that way would make things significantly easier.

Comment: then how can we achieve

Comment: Your code in your `Seats` object only changes the colour in the `init`.  Move that `if` to a `didSet` on `isSelected`.  Move the individual seat views into their own `View` class so that you can pass a value to an `@Binding var seat: Seats` (Also, avoid plurals in object names, as you can see `Seat` makes more sense than `Seats`

Comment: Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app, just copy and paste the examples into your code 
[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)

Comment: can you pls explain with code?

Comment: yes, have a look at the link, it has code you use in your App and is well explained.

Comment: much confusing there not able to relate with my code coz no actual model is used there :(

Comment: if possible pls explain with code

Comment: Give it a go, try something by yourself. Take the advice given,
 no nesting of ObservableObjects, use structs, read the official docs. Then show us what
 is not working.

Comment: BUT I am getting the data from the API as nested object then definitely we would need to create the object in same way, I don't know how can we avoid nesting then

Comment: Take the advice, use `struct`, then you can nest them and decode them. Not nesting ObservableObjects classes.

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick worked for me:

in GateSectionView in have refreshed the array with the help of reversed()

```
ForEach(Array(data.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, element in
  Button {
      data.reverse()
      element.toggleIsSelectedStatus()
      data.reverse()
  } label: {
     Text(element.seatNumber ?? "")
           
   }
```